# Rellenar un DataGridView con número de columnas variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Recientemente me he puesto a trabajar en ASP.Net, con sus aspx y sus aspx.vb... 
Necesito hacer algo que nunca he hecho, y no se muy bien como plantearlo:
Tengo unos datos que  extraigo de una BD tal que así:

```
|   Nombre   |  Descripción  |  Fecha  |
---------------------------------------
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 |   Dia1  |
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 |   Dia2  |
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 |   Dia3  |
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 |   DiaN  |
```

En código tengo que dejar esta tabla de datos en la forma:

```
|   Nombre   |  Descripción  |   Dia1   |   Dia2   |   Dia3   |   DiaN   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 | ComboBox | ComboBox | ComboBox | ComboBox |
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 | ComboBox | ComboBox | ComboBox | ComboBox |
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 | ComboBox | ComboBox | ComboBox | ComboBox |
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 | ComboBox | ComboBox | ComboBox | ComboBox |
```

Las dudas de si podré hacer esto, empiezan aquí:
- Hasta donde yo se, en el aspx tienes que indicar las columnas que va a tener la tabla, y como en este caso, el número de columnas de la tabla va a depender del número de días, no sabría como solucionar esto. (Por lo que he leído, con DataGridView, desde el aspx.vb, igual puedo, aunque no se como)
- Suponiendo que fuera capaz de generar esta tabla dinámicamente, necesito que se muestren esos ComboBox , en donde poder seleccionar unos valores para después poder insertar esto de nuevo en otra tabla con esos valores selecionados en el ComboBox, tal que asi:

```
|   Nombre   |  Descripción  |  Fecha  |  ValorCombo  |
------------------------------------------------------
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 |   Dia1  |     Valor    |
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 |   Dia2  |     Valor    |
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 |   Dia3  |     Valor    |
|   Nombre1  | Descripción 1 |   DiaN  |     Valor    |
```

No se si me podréis poner un poco en el camino para resolver esto...

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Estimado, lo que planteas es fácil de solucionar con un DataGridView, pero para poder ayudarte hace falta tu código para poder hacer ejemplos funcionales y darte una buena respuesta.

Comment: Hola Harifo, la cosa es que todavía no tengo código, de momento estoy viendo solo  la viabilidad de esto...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como respuesta, imaginando un poco tu código debería ser lo siguiente.

Todo en tu aspx.vb

```
'Primero

Dim columnaCombo As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

columnaCombo.Name = "Columna Combobox"

DataGridView1.Columns.Add(columnaCombo)


'Segundo, En el evento cell click de mi grilla transformo la columna y le asigno Fuentes de datos:

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        Dim columna As Integer
        Dim fila As Integer
        columna = DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X
        fila = DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.Y

        Dim comboboxColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = TryCast(DataGridView1.Rows(fila).Cells(columna), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        comboboxColumn.DataSource = fun_comprobante.Cargar_Combo_Tipo_Actor
        comboboxColumn.DisplayMember = "tipo"
        comboboxColumn.ValueMember = "tipo"

End Sub
```

Y para llenar tu DGV con el número de días, solo hace falta llamar un dataTable con la data que necesitaras

```
 Dim dt as new dataTable = cn.DataTable("SELECT * from miTabla")
 DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.clone()
```

Si tienes alguna consulta, no dudes en preguntar!

Comment: Gracias! me pongo a estudiar esto a ver si logro adaptarlo!

Comment: @JoséPabloMedinaGrande recuerda que si la respuesta te sirve, debes marcarla como correcta para que ayude a otros con tu misma duda